# How to pass a string from a view to its view model in Xamarin forms using mvvm light

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

My view takes in a json string via its constructor, I then want to immediately pass the string to its view model. I am very new to Xamarin.forms and an note sure how I should go about doing this.  I think I am supposed to use Commanding somehow.  I am using the MvvmLightLibs NuGet by Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft) if that helps.

Here is some code. I am using a file picker to get a json file, then I deserialize it and get the text

```
FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();

fileName = fileData.FileName;

if (fileName.EndsWith(".json", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))

{                        
     MockJsonFile mockJsonFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MockJsonFile>(File.ReadAllText(fileData.FilePath));
     string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mockJsonFile, Formatting.Indented);                       
     FilePathlabel.Text = json;                                                         
}
```

This is done in the code behind of what I will call view1. I am trying to send this text to view1's view model "viewModel1".  If I can get that done, I can then navigate from viewModel1 to view2, passing the string into view2's constructor as so...

```
public void GoToView2(string jsonString)
{
     _navigationService.NavigateTo(ViewModelLocator.view2, jsonString);
}
```

From here I can use whatever process I used to pass the string from view1 to viewModel1 to do the same thing for view2 to viewModel2. From what I have read, you want to avoid using messaging center when using MVVM (could be wrong on that) so I am trying to figure out what the proper way is to send simple values/objects from view to viewModel.

Answer (score 0):

try using `Messaging Center`

[Here's a link to help you,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

I'd still like to know what is the use case and if there can be a better approach, because I'm sure there can be. show us some code.

Comment: I added some code. From what I have read, I was under the impression using messaging center should be avoided in mvvm.  Basically, I am trying to figure out how to send simple values/objects from the view to the view model.